# MySQL: Order by specific items first then by time

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

Lets say we have a table

```
names
-------------------
id     name      created_at
1      alpha     2020-10-23 17:30:35
2      beta      2020-10-24 17:30:35
3      gamma     2020-10-25 17:30:35
4      kilo      2020-10-26 17:30:35
5      charlie   2020-10-27 17:30:35
6      hector    2020-10-28 17:30:35
```

I want to order the first few rows by a fixed array let's say `6,3,2` and the rest by `created_at` in desc order.
So the order that I'm expecting would be `6,3,2,5,4,1`.

How can I achieve this using Mysql ?

I tried using field() but can't get it to work with the other column.

Comment: Just use FIELD()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FIELD()` is tricky for this, because it returns `0` if there are no matches.  You can construct an expression that does what you want:

```
order by coalesce(nullif(field(id, 6, 3, 2), 0), 999999),
         created_at desc
```

If you know that the ids are always descending for the fixed values, then you can use:

```
order by (case when id in (6, 3, 2) then id end) desc,
         created_at desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY (
CASE
    WHEN id = 6 THEN 1
    WHEN id = 3 THEN 2
    WHEN id = 2 THEN 3
    ELSE 4
END, created_at DESC
)
```

The `CASE` statement ensures the first 3 items listed are 6, 3 and 2, and the rest are listed in `created_at DESC` order.

Answer (score -1):

One option would be to write a case expression as follows

```
  select *
    from names
order by case when id in (6,3,2) then 0
              else 1
          end asc,created_at desc
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but the question seems pretty clear that 6/3/2 is fixed in their ordering and not ordered by create date (although the data is ambiguous on that point).

Comment: i wonder on the downvote, based on the data as it exists now you can find the results of this query is 6,3,2 followed by 5,4,1. Also i assumed that for each incremental id the datetime would is increasing. Here is my full test case https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fc48064dc59f9c25bda3b44e187f1a79

Comment: I didn't downvote but I also suspected this answer was wrong because ordering by 0 when id is in (6,3,2) means those three records will be ordered by `created_at DESC`. Now, because of those records' dates, that just *happens* to be the OP's requested order, but if the dates ever change then they will no longer be retrieved in 6,3,2 order. In other words, if you want to guarantee 6,3,2 order, you must explicitly specify that in the `ORDER BY` clause, as I did in my response.